Type mismatch for custom generic type in Kotlin
In Kotlin I can write:
fun foo(): List<String> {
    return ArrayList<String>().apply { this.add("1234") }
}

and it works without any issues.
But I tried to do the same with my own generic class:
 fun bar(): Matcher<String> {
     return MyJsonNullableMatcher()
 }

and I see error:
Type mismatch.
Required:
Matcher<String>
Found:
MyJsonNullableMatcher<String>

for me the error looks very unclear
More details:
import org.hamcrest.Matcher
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher

class MyJsonNullableMatcher<T> : TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher<JsonNullable<T>>() {

    override fun describeTo(desc: Description) {
        // doesn't matter
    }

    override fun matchesSafely(actual: JsonNullable<T>, mismatchDescription: Description): Boolean {
         // doesn't matter
        return true
    }
}

TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher is an descendant of org.hamcrest.Matcher
Could you please clarify ?

What do you mean by saying your first code sample "works without any issues"? This part: .apply { "1234" } does nothing, it is entirely ignored.

@broot I mean it doesn't lead to  compilation errors. Thank you for you comment -corrected a bit but it doesn't affect the issue

MyJsonNullableMatcher<String> is  Matcher<JsonNullable<String>>
but not Matcher<String>
So this will be correct:
 fun bar(): Matcher<JsonNullable<String>> {
     return MyJsonNullableMatcher()
 }

